# React:Passing data from TextField in index.tsx file to hooks.js where we are dispatching

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, formik

First let me say that I am a developer with background in angular that just took react project so please forgive my ignorance(I am totally new to react and wasnt left with a lot of time to learn it).
I have to add a new textfield 'DispatcherComments' in index.tsx file and pass it to hooks.ts file.I added the textfield but i am struggling to update DispatcherComments in hooks.ts.

In index.tsx file I gave a TextField whose value that I need to pass has a name name="DispatcherComments" and in hooks.ts at the end is the dispatch method where i have put property that needs to be updated 'DispatcherComments'
index.tsx:

```
interface IEventCreateModal {
  handleCloseModal: () => void,
  resourceRecord: {
    [key:string]: any,
  },
  eventRecord: {
    [key: string]: any,
  },
}

const EventCreateModal = ({
  handleCloseModal,
  resourceRecord,
  eventRecord,
}: IEventCreateModal) => {
  const {
    data: {
      loading,
      resourcesOptions,
      projectsOptions,
      initialValues,
      projects,
    },
    actions: { handleCreateEvent },
  } = useEventCreateModal({
    resourceRecord,
    eventRecord,
  });

  const submit = (values: any) => 
  handleCreateEvent(values);

  return (
    <Dialog
      open
      fullWidth
      maxWidth="sm"
      aria-labelledby="event-dialog"
      disableBackdropClick
      disableEscapeKeyDown
    >
      <DialogTitle
        id="event-dialog"
        style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
      >
        {t('newEvent')}
      </DialogTitle>

      <DialogContent>
        <Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          onSubmit={submit}
          validate={validate}
          enableReinitialize
        >
          {({
            handleSubmit,
            errors,
            touched,
            values,
          }:any) => (
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField id="outlined-basic" 
                   label={t('commentOptional')} 
                   name="DispatcherComments"
                   //onChange={changeState}
                   //onChange = {e => setDispatcherComments(e.target.value)}
                   //onChange={handleChange}
                   //value={dispatcherComments}
                   variant="outlined"
                   fullWidth/>
            </Grid>

              </Grid>

              <ModalButtonWrap>
                <Button onClick={handleCloseModal} variant="outlined" disabled={loading}>


                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" disabled={loading}>
                  <ButtonCircularProgress loading={loading} label={t('createEvent')} />
                </Button>
              </ModalButtonWrap>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

EventCreateModal.propTypes = {
  handleCloseModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default EventCreateModal;
```

hooks.ts

```
interface IuseEventCreateModal {
  resourceRecord: {
    [key:string]: any,
  },
  eventRecord: {
    [key:string]: any,
  },
}

const useEventCreateModal = ({
  resourceRecord,
  eventRecord,
  
}: IuseEventCreateModal) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector(selector);
  const handleCreateEvent = useCallback((values: any) => {

    const {
      ResourceId,
      ProjectDate,
      StartTime,
      EndDate,
      EndTime,
      ProjectID,
      DispatcherComments,
    } = values;
    


    dispatch(createEvent({

      DispatcherComments
    }));
  }, [dispatch, DispatcherComments]);

  return {
    data: {
      loading: data.loading,
      initialValues: {
        DispatcherComments:''
      },
    },
    actions: { handleCreateEvent },
  };
};

export default useEventCreateModal;
```

Comment: I think we may disagree what a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is. When you need help then I would advice creating minimal code that shows the problem instead of doing a copy paste dump of code from your project.

Comment: It is also not clear what you are asking, what actions are dispatched and what changes do they make to the state (use redux-devtools)? What in any of these things "is not working"?

Comment: @HMR I apologise for not being clearer.I edited the code and removed everything except the TextField and its property.In index file i set the default value and get the output when i change the value  but in the hooks.ts  the actual state of property 'DispatcherComments' stays empty. So my problem is that I don't know how to pass it/make it available to the create function..

Comment: Thank you for updating the question, can you try giving the text input a value and onChange prop like in the [formix example](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#example)?

Comment: @HMR Thanks a lot for your hint, I ended up with `<DialogContent>
<Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={data =>{ handleCreateEvent(data);}}` & `<Grid item xs={12}>
<TextField label={t('commentOptional')} name="DispatcherComments"
onChange={handleChange} value={values.DispatcherComments} variant="outlined"
fullWidth/></Grid>` and now it works as expected, would you mind putting it in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [example](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#example), I assumed you did something like this:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={(data) => {
    handleCreateEvent(data);
  }}
>
  {(props) => (
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <TextField
        label={t('commentOptional')}
        name="DispatcherComments"
        onChange={props.handleChange}//add onchange
        value={props.values.DispatcherComments}//add value
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
      />
    </Grid>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, would you mind looking at this question as well, maybe you could help me out there as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68844472/pushing-history-according-to-previously-selected-filters-from-localstorage